# Using Itext to generate pdf files a

Tags: android

I am using Itext to generate pdf files  ... When I try to save a file in Arabic it is coming as blank  where as for English it is able to generate text in pdf file.

```
     File file = new File(pdfPath,"INVOICE"+"_"+ i  + "_"+t+"_"+ Date+".pdf");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.add("नमस्ते ")  ;
        document.add(paragraph);
        float columnWidth[] = {140,140,140,140};
        Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
        String s = "      __    مرحبا       __   " ;
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(" Invoice")) .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(s)).setBold() .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(" ")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("# 00000000000")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should use a font support Arabic like Arial, then you have to use add-on called pdfcalligraph in itext7 which not free.

or you have to do it your self:

1. first you have to get Arial font to use.
2. use replacement for pdfcalligraph which pick the right glyph for character  "As you know there is more than one shape for each Arabic char" a [AraibcPdfUnicodeGlyphsResharper](https://github.com/ibrhabash/AraibcPdfUnicodeGlyphsResharper) can help in that as follow:

   ```
   //Use the class provided in link
   using AraibcPdfUnicodeGlyphsResharper;

   File file = new File(pdfPath,"INVOICE"+"_"+ i  + "_"+t+"_"+ Date+".pdf");
   OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
   PdfFont xPdfFont = CreateFont("path for font support arabic like arial", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);

   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
   Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
   // font must be set for document or for cell,Paragraph any think used to print Arabic
   document.SetFont(xPdfFont)
   Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
       paragraph.add("नमस्ते ")  ;
       document.add(paragraph);
       float columnWidth[] = {140,140,140,140};
       Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
   //must call ArabicWithFontGlyphsToPfd() method 
       String s = "      __    مرحبا       __   ".ArabicWithFontGlyphsToPfd(); ;
       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(" Invoice")) .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(s)).setBold() .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(" ")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("# 00000000000")).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
       document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
   ```

```
  


  [1]: https://github.com/ibrhabash/AraibcPdfUnicodeGlyphsResharper
```